# Form population from checkbox selection

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is a somewhat simplified version of the problem to make it easier to explain and a shorter question.

I have X checkboxes:

```
<input type="checkbox" class="checker" value="1" />
<input type="checkbox" class="checker" value="2" />
<input type="checkbox" class="checker" value="3" />
...
```

I have 2 columns, cert and cost, of Y number of input fields (X > Y) then a total at the bottom:

```
<input type="text" class="cert" /><input type="text" class="cost">
<input type="text" class="cert" /><input type="text" class="cost">
<input type="text" class="cert" /><input type="text" class="cost">
...

<input type="text" id="total" />
```

The user can select any combination of checkboxes (up to limit Y). When a checkbox is selected, it's value is entered into the first empty cert input. Depending on the cert value, the corresponding cost is then put into the adjacent cost input (e.g. cert 1 = cost 50, cert 2 = cost 100, etc).

If a checkbox is unticked, the corresponding cert is cleared, as is the cost.

The total at the bottom keeps a running total on a change to any thing.

A few additional notes:

- The checkboxes are spaced throughout the form, not in one continual sequence.
- Similarly the cert and cost inputs are not actually side by side in the html (although do appear to be on the screen), there is other code between them.

Any help / input is greatly appreciated as I'm mostly just producing a mess!

Comment: Have you given your input elements IDs? That's probably your first step to being able to differentiate them from one another.

Comment: Can you show us what you tried?

Answer (score 1):

Here is something to start you out with.  I'm not sure if your `cert 1` `cert 2` is going inside the textbox or there are labels or something.  Same with your cost.  But that's the way I did it in the example.  This is assuming you have the same amount of checkboxes as the set of inputs(cert & cost);

```
$('input.checker').change(function(){
    // store the current index so we can pick which text input to change
    var $i = $(this).index('input.checker');
    // put val in corresponding cert text input
    $('input.cert').eq($i).val(this.checked ? 'cert ' + ($i+1) : '');
    // put val in corresponding .cost text input
    $('input.cost').eq($i).val(this.checked ? 'cost ' + (50 * ($i+1)) : '');

    var total = 0;
    // loop through the cost inputs and add up total
    $('input.cost').each(function(i,v){
        total += (+$(v).val().replace('cost ',''));
    });
    // insert total
    $('#total').val(total);
});​
```

**[EXAMPLE FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/vqdps/1/)**